# Is Reaving Dispel strictly better than Greater Dispel Magic?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

I've seen Reaving Dispel listed as a strictly superior (i.e. *always* better) replacement for Greater Dispel Magic, provided that you don't care about the spell slot cost difference. Having read the text of Reaving Dispel, I'm not so sure. It appears to do many things that Greater Dispel Magic does not, so I've become confused. Is Reaving Dispel always better than Greater Dispel Magic?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Yes, aside from spell level

Which is a ridiculous thing to ignore, but nonetheless.

> This spell functions like *dispel magic*, except that the maximum caster level on your dispel check is +20 instead of +10.
>
> Additionally, *greater dispel magic* has a chance to dispel any effect that *remove curse* can remove, even if *dispel magic* can’t dispel that effect.

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook*, *greater dispel magic* description)</sup>

> This spell functions like *dispel magic* (*PH* 223), except that your caster level for your dispel check is a maximum of +20 instead of +10, and (as with *greater dispel magic*) you have a chance to dispel any effect that *remove curse* can remove, even if *dispel magic* can’t dispel that effect. When casting a targeted dispel or counterspell, you **can** choose to reave each spell you successfully dispel, stealing its power and effect for yourself.

<sup>(*Spell Compendium*, *reaving dispel* description, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

*Reaving dispel* has every feature that *greater dispel magic* has, plus the reaving feature. Since reaving is wholly optional, you can use *reaving dispel* exactly as if it were *greater dispel magic*. That plus an additional feature is strict superiority.

Again, ignoring spell level, which shouldn’t be ignored.

Comment: If you don't like the characterization of the spell as strictly better because of the difference in spell level, you could instead say that the effect is strictly better/more powerful.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Except I *want* to emphasize the failures of that analysis. I don’t to sidestep that at all.

Comment: You need high level divination for *reaving dispel* to actually be better. *Analyze dweomer* is 6th level and 1 round/lvl; *greater arcane sight* is a more useful 1 min./lvl, but 7th level. With normal *detect magic* or *arcane sight*, you can't tell the difference between *mass bull's strength* and *Tenser's transformation*, or *death ward* and *bestow curse*. *Reaving dispel* is usually better, but can go comically wrong.

Comment: @Prevarications You don’t need any divination (though such things are commonly considered convenient for mages of this level); it has a built-in opportunity to identify each spell effect (DC 25 + spell level Spellcraft check, which is not hard at this level) before you decide whether or not to race that effect. If you fail to identify an effect, then you’re gambling, but most casters of this spell shouldn’t fail often at all.

Comment: Whoops. It happened to a party member years ago, but I guess he either flubbed the roll or didn't have Spellcraft trained. Rereading the description, I guess *reaving dispel* really is strictly better than a *heightened greater dispel magic*. Very useful for, uh, churning through *spell turning* faster and using up those pesky excess 9th level spell slots.